# Threading issue with UICollectionview loading images from CloudKit

Tags: multithreading, ios8, uicollectionview, cloudkit

I'm having a threading issue loading images in a collectionview where the data is coming from cloudkit. I know this is a threading/blocking issue because before I implemented CK, I dumped some images in a folder on my desktop and read/parsed them from there and had no issue. With CK, I just created a handful of records via the dashboard and I'm successfully getting the expected records returned and use the images from those results to populate the CV cells. I store the CK query results in an array and use the size of that array to set the numberOfItemsInSection delegate.

Here's the issue...in the numberOfItemsInSection delegate method, I'm calling the model class, which executes the CK query. Since that is obviously a network call, I put that in a background thread. From logging, I can see the query execute and the results come back very quickly - within 2-3 seconds. However, the CV cells never display and I don't see the custom cell get initialized (via logging). But if I tap the camera button and take a photo, which I've implemented, I take the resulting image and add it to the array, then call reloadData on the CV and all the cells (and images) appear, including the new image just taken with the camera.

By accident, I found out a hack that somewhat works, which is calling reloadData on the CV *inside* the background thread of the numberOfItemsInSection delegate method. As a result, I thought I might have stumbled on to the solution by switching back to the main thread when calling reloadData, but that put it in a sort of endless loop of continuously calling the numberOfItemsInSection method and cellForItemAtIndexPath and made it to where it lagged to a point that you could barely scroll and tapping on any of the cells wouldn't do anything.

At this point, after trying many, many various things, I'm at a complete loss on how to fix this. I know this is probably a pretty easy solution as it's very common to load images asynchronously to populate a collectionview or tableview. Can someone please provide some guidance? Thanks in advance!!!

```
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger numberOfItemsInSection;

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSLog(@"***numberOfItemsInSection***");

    dispatch_queue_t fetchQ = dispatch_queue_create("load image data", NULL);
    dispatch_async(fetchQ, ^{
        self.numberOfItemsInSection = [self.imageLoadManager.imageDataArray count];
        [self.myCollectionView reloadData]; // should be done on main thread!
    });
    NSLog(@"numberOfItemsInSection: %ld", (long)self.numberOfItemsInSection);

    return self.numberOfItemsInSection;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell"; // string value identifier for cell reuse
    ImageViewCell *cell = [collectionView  dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"cellForItemAtIndexPath: section:%ld row:%ld", (long)indexPath.section, (long)indexPath.row);
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    cell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
    cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    ImageData *imageData = [self.imageLoadManager imageDataForCell:indexPath.row]; // maps the model to the UI
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (imageData.imageURL.path) {
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imageData.imageURL.path];
            [cell setNeedsLayout];
        } else {
            // if imageURL is nil, then image is coming in from the camera as opposed to the cloud
            cell.imageView.image = imageData.image;
            [cell setNeedsLayout];
        }
    }); 

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: *Don't guess.*  Reason out the problem, figure out what the problem is, and then code a solution to solve that specific problem.  Threads can be difficult to reason about; make sure you are well-versed in the coding techniques that allow you to use them safely.

Answer (score 0):

before returning self.numberOfItemsInSection you should wait until the async call is finished. You can do that using semaphores. But then why are you doing this async? You are just getting the count of an array. And then you shouldn't reloadData there. Where do you start your CloudKit query? are you doing that onViewDidLoad? That is also an async operation. When that completes just doe a reloadData of your collectionView. Besides that doing this would be enough:

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.imageLoadManager.imageDataArray count];
}
```

If you really want to use async there, then you do have to wait for the result. You could change your code to something like:

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSLog(@"***numberOfItemsInSection***");

    dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    dispatch_queue_t fetchQ = dispatch_queue_create("load image data", NULL);
    dispatch_async(fetchQ, ^{
        self.numberOfItemsInSection = [self.imageLoadManager.imageDataArray count];
        [self.myCollectionView reloadData]; // should be done on main thread!
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
    });
    NSLog(@"numberOfItemsInSection: %ld", (long)self.numberOfItemsInSection);

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    return self.numberOfItemsInSection;
}
```

And then why do you go to the main queue in cellForItemAtIndexPath? It's already executed on the main queue.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm doing this async because the below line is what kicks off the CK query in the model...ImageLoadManager is the model class.
self.numberOfItemsInSection = [self.imageLoadManager.imageDataArray count];

Comment: OK, but then the CloudKit query itself is already async. You don't have to wrap it. You then do have to make sure that the CloudKit query is ready before you do the count. You could use the semaphore structure for that.

Comment: Yeah, and that was part of my question...I wasn't sure exactly how to do this now that I'm getting the data remotely. I was pretty sure it was wrong, but wasn't sure what the "right way" to do it was. 

I've never heard of semaphores, but I just tried your code and got an error on the var sema line - use of undeclared identifier - var. Are you using Swift syntax? I'll have to google semaphores. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: I googled semaphores and was able to get your code working, but there was no difference at all in the results....CV doesn't render unless I take a pic, which ends up triggering the CV custom cell code to render. The only way this has worked at all is with my original code above where I do the async call to the model and load the CK data AND call reloadData on the CV in the background thread, which I know is incorrect.

Comment: ha funny i inserted Swift code into your objective C sample. Will now update it for you...

Comment: Add extra NSLog statements in various places in your code. I bet the function will return the numberOfItemsInSection before CloucKit has returned your data. I usually fetch data in the viewDidLoad. Then when that async call finishes then call the reloadData. Then you only have to get the count of the already fetched data.

Comment: Thanks! However, after you mentioned semaphores, I did a quick google search and was able to easily get the Swift code changed to objective-c, which ended up exactly as you edited it above. But the results were the same, unfortunately. And you are absolutely correct about numberOfItemsInSection being returned before CK data is returned...I had been watching that already. Also, I had the same thought as you and tried to call the CK query in VDL and set the numberOfItemsInSection property there before the CV is even set up, but that didn't work either. Really frustrating.

Comment: Actually, moving the CK query call to VDL made it even worse. The numberOfItemsInSection property is printing as 0, so the CV cells obviously never load. I'm not sure if this is a thread deadlock issue that is never executed as I'm not sure how to check for that, but that would be my suspicion.

Comment: you do have to call a reloadData the moment your CK query is ready and the data is there. Then the numberOfItemsInSection will be triggered and can return the count for that

Comment: I only had a small amount of time to mess with it yesterday, but I'll continue to play with it and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Edwin, I'm at a total loss, can't figure this out. If you look at my numberOfItems method above, that's the only thing that remotely works, i.e. CV cells load without taking a photo and adding to the array. But it crashes most of the time when running on the device. If I follow your code with semaphores, cells only load after taking a photo. It does not appear that it's waiting for the CK data to return before continuing to process. Also, with my code, the numberOfitems property almost always logs 1 < than array count. With your code, it always logs = to the array count, which is correct. Odd.

Comment: semaphores are only necessary when you want to make an async call synchronous. Jus start the CloudKit query in the viewDidLoad. If you then make sure that you do a reloaddata when the result of your CloudKit query is ready, then there is no need for semaphores.

Comment: I had played around with that earlier as well with no success. Should I do that (CK query from inside VDL) in a background thread?

Comment: Does not work at all. I tried every possible way I could think of doing it within VDL - no thread, a background thread like I have above in the delegate method, using your semaphore suggestion, etc. The result is that the CV cells will NEVER render, even if I take a photo. Getting them to render only after taking a photo was my original issue. I also tried calling reloadData in various places, all with the same result. 
It really looks like I need to do in the delegate and force everything to wait until the CK data returns. If you're willing, I could send you the link to my code. Thanks.

Comment: Here is a good sample of how to do it. It's for a tableview, but the structure should be the same: https://github.com/ghvillasboas/CloudKitTest/blob/master/CloudKitTest/CloudKitTableViewController.m

Comment: Edwin - that example code you provided worked! Difference in what I was doing and that example is that I was using my model class to execute the CK query and parse/store the results, then providing that back to the controller to update the view. I like my way better, but obviously there's a threading issue and lack of understanding of it on my part. I still need to clean things up a bit and do some more refactoring, but it is actually working now. I can't thank you enough for the help and patience!

Comment: Your welcome. If you do want to execute the CK query from your model class, then make sure you also pass on a callback event so that your model can do a callback to your controller for executing the reloaddata

Comment: As in adding a protocol to the VC that will allow me to do a callback from the model class as soon as the CK query is returned?

Comment: I thought about your comment about doing the callback from the model to the controller and that seemed like *the* solution to the problem I was having in my original code. However, if I'm understanding you correctly, that would be a very bad MVC design. I would have to create a protocol in my VC and have my model conform to it so I could do the callback. i.e. model talking directly to the VC.

So I assume I must not be completely understanding your suggestion.

Comment: Yes, you are right, a protocol would not be the best way to go. What I meant was that you could use a code block and pass that on as a parameter to the method that does the KC query. For more information about codeblocks, see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html

Comment: Edwin - I'm just now getting around to your suggestion a few comments above (Nov 14 at 20:08), where you recommended passing a callback event to my model when calling my CloudKit query so it can callback to the VC. I've just been living with the way I had it where I call the CK query directly from the VC, but it's time to clean this up and do it properly. However, I realized I don't really understand it enough to know exactly what it is that I'm trying to do. Can you point me to an example of passing a callback event like you recommended? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's the way I do everything in https://github.com/evermeer/EVCloudKitDao For instance look at the 'EVCloudData.publicDB.connect(News(), ...'  sample on that page then you can see that it's using 5 different handlers that are used as callback blocks.

Comment: Maybe this sample is easier to follow: https://gist.github.com/szehnder/84b0bd6f45a7f3f99306

Comment: Thank you, sir! Do you happen to have a previous objective-c version or was it only done in Swift? I can still make sense of it in Swift, but objective-c would be easier.

Comment: It was all done in Swift. Ray Wenderlich always have nice tutorials. I think this can help: http://www.raywenderlich.com/9438/how-to-use-blocks-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-2